# DataGrid Autogenerated columns: Increasing width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to increase the width of auto-generated columns by a fixed amount? I'm trying to do the following but it doesn't work:

```
private void dgvMailingList_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
     e.Column.Width += 30; 
}
```

Even `e.Column.Width = e.Column.Width + 30;` doesn't work because the default `UnitType` of `Width` is `Auto` and therefore `e.Column.Width` returns `1.0` instead of the actual pixel width. `UnitType` itself is read-only, so can't play with that either. `ActualWidth` is also set to `0` in `AutoGeneratingColumn` event. What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You want same column width for all columns?

Comment: @RohitVats: Thanks. I simply want these columns to be 30 pixels wider than the width assigned during auto-generation. The auto-generated width is just enough to fit the contents, I want it to look at little wider. The primary problem is that I'm not able to get the current value of width in pixels inside AutoGeneratingColumns event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Columns are not rendered yet on UI when `AutoGeneratingColumns` event is raised. Hence ActualWidth is 0.0.

Use **`Loaded`** event to loop over columns and increase width by constant factor you want.

```
private void dataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var column in ((DataGrid)sender).Columns)
    {
        column.Width = new DataGridLength(column.ActualWidth + 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. One caveat though. Is there a way to invoke this event manually? I'll need this resizing to be done upon the click of a button.

Comment: Yeah put this in click handler of button. But to get dataGrid, you need to set `x:Name` on it in XAML and access it by name in code behind.